# Problems with powering on the "Taotronics tt-bh085"

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I hope this is the right forum, otherwise please tell me and I will take the post down.

I have had the above-mentioned overear headphones for almost half a year and so far they have actually worked without any problems.
However, I can no longer turn on the headphones.

When I plug them in, the charging LED lights up blue after a while, even when I activate ANC it works and lights up blue. When I connect the headphones with a cable, everything works perfectly. But it is not possible to turn them on normally.

Could someone help me here or know how to reset the headphones.

Answer (score 0):

This from another user...

Mine did the same. Leave the ANC (Anti-Noise Cancellation) on until the battery is totally discharged then charge and use normally. Hope it works with you guys!
It's sort of a glitch when disconnected from PC by turning airplane mode on

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly I can't try it since I don't have them anymore. I was able to send them back, now i have the Anker Soundcore Q30. But I have to say those are definetely better, but also more costly. However everything turned out well for me.